# Delete fragment as user swipe on fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement FINISH() on my fragment-adapter. I just want to know what possible code should I use as the user swipe fragments the SWIPED fragments are removed....

My code for the adapter:

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter
{    
    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = new Question1();
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Question1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Question2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Question3();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Question4();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Question5();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new FinalPage();
            break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        String title = "";
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            title = "Question 1";
            break;
        case 1:
            title = "Question 2";
            break;
        case 2:
            title = "Question 3";
            break;
        case 3:
            title = "Question 4";
            break;
        case 4:
            title = "Question 5";
            break;
        case 5:
            title = "Submit Quiz";
            break;
        }

            return title;
    }
}
```

And my code for the Activity:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends FragmentActivity
{   
    FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mPageIndicator;
    String share_name = "Q1_Answer";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager1);

        mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mPageIndicator = (PageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mPageIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the overrides called when the swipe state is changed (ie for moving, stopped, ...)?

Comment: Ahm. Actually I want to delete a fragment after a page swipe.. EXAMPLE... My app is a quiz.. Im on QUESTION 1. So I have finished answering.. Then swipe to QUESTION 2.. The thing is I want to remove QUESTION 1 so the user cannot go back..

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying for me. Are you using a ViewPager?

Comment: yes sir.. Im using a viewpager..

Answer (score 0):

When working with fragments within a ViewPager, anytime you want to manipulate the Fragments, you should manipulate the List object that is passed into the PagerAdapter, and then call notifyDataSetChanged on the PagerAdapter object.

For example:

```
List<Fragment> mFragments = new List<Fragment>();
mFragments.Add(frag1);
mFragments.Add(frag2);

FragmentStatePagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
pagerAdapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager, mFragments, this);

ViewPager viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.view_pager);
viewPager.Adapter = pagerAdapter;

...

mFragments.Remove(0);

pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
pagerAdapter.setCurrentItem(0, false);
```

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work (and please check as answer otherwise thanks).